# I restricted the words in the tweets to content words now I want to Transform the words to lower case and add the POS with an underderscore

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk, spacy

I wrote the code below and restrict the words in the tweets to content words, i.e., nouns, verbs, and adjectives, Now I want to Transform the words to lower case and add the POS with an underderscore. E.g.:

love_VERB old-fashioneds_NOUN
but I dont know how, can anyone help me?

```
! pip install wget
import wget
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dirkhovy/NLPclass/master/data/reviews.full.tsv.zip'
wget.download(url, 'reviews.full.tsv.zip')


from zipfile import ZipFile
with ZipFile('reviews.full.tsv.zip', 'r') as zf:
    zf.extractall()


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('reviews.full.tsv', sep='\t', nrows=100000) # nrows , max amount of rows 
documents = df.text.values.tolist()
print(documents[:4])


import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') #you can use other methods
# excluded tags
included_tags = {"NOUN", "VERB", "ADJ"}
#document = [line.strip() for line in open('moby_dick.txt', encoding='utf8').readlines()]

sentences = documents[:103] #first 10 sentences
new_sentences = []
for sentence in sentences:
    new_sentence = []
    for token in nlp(sentence):
        if token.pos_  in included_tags:
            new_sentence.append(token.text)
    new_sentences.append(" ".join(new_sentence))

#Creates a list of lists of tokens
tokens = [[token.text for token in nlp(new_sentence)] for new_sentence in documents[:200]]
tokens

# import itertools
# tok = itertools.chain.from_iterable(
#    [[token.text for token in nlp(new_sentence)] for new_sentence in documents[:200]])

# tok
```

Comment: kindly post samples of ur token lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you change

```
        new_sentence.append(token.text)
```

to

```
        new_sentence.append(token.text.lower()+'_'+token.POS)
```

you'll have what you are after.

Comment: thank you, with a very small change is like this : new_sentence.append(token.text.lower()+'_'+token.pos_